# Implementing Actuator with spring boot microservice architecture

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-boot-actuator

I am using  spring boot and microservice architecture for my project. I want to check health of my application.

I have 3 services registered with eureka-server.

I am able to check health for eureka-server but how to know about health of other services?

http://localhost:8080/actuator/health

This is working but http://localhost:8080/api/user-service/actuator/health is not working

Please help with the approach.

Thanks!

Comment: each microservice expose that endpoint in their own process. You should check for example http://localhost:(port)/actuator/health to be able to see it. You may also use this which collects those information for you into a central place: https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you really want to use this url `http://localhost:8080/api/user-service/actuator/health` for health check, then you have to set a context path for actuator.

You can use the following property,

```
management.context-path = /user-service
```

But this is **not really recommended**, Since you are still hitting LoadBalancer (I assume zuul in your case). 
Say you have 3 instances of Application is running and suddenly one instance is down, and you are still hitting the loadbalancer for healthcheck, it won't say that an instance is down until all goes down.

So In your case you can use the **healthcheck url that used by eureka server**.(If you go to Eureka's console you can get it from there).

Or use a **Monitoring tool** (This is the standard approach)